# How to remove Rails-Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I thought I've removed Rails-Admin from my app.
However, when I push my app to Heroku,the error occurres about Rails-Admin and failed to push.

here's the way I tried:

1.remove Rails-Admin from Gemfile

2.run bundle install

3.remove config/initializers/rails_admin.rb file

4.remove description about Rails-Admin from routes.rb

5.restart app

I searched "rails-admin""rails_admin" in the app by Atom's search function,
there was no result.

config/environments/production.rb⬇️

```
Rails.application.configure do
...
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
...
end
```

config/application.rb⬇️

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module KomoService
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.2
    config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'
    config.generators do |g|
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
      g.test_framework :rspec,
                       fixtures: true,
                       view_specs: false,
                       helper_specs: false,
                       routing_specs: false,
                       controller_specs: true,
                       request_specs: false
      g.fixture_refuneral_hallsment :factory_bot, dir: "spec/factories"
    end

    config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.yml').to_s]
  end
end
```

```
Enumerating objects: 1698, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1593/1593), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1377/1377), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1488/1488), 358.06 KiB | 5.59 MiB/s, done.
Total 1488 (delta 962), reused 124 (delta 85)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        Your app was upgraded to bundler 2.0.2.
remote:        Previously you had a successful deploy with bundler 2.0.1.
remote:        
remote:        If you see problems related to the bundler version please refer to:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues
remote:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Using rake 12.3.2
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.4
remote:        Using minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubi 1.8.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.4
remote:        Using rack 2.0.6
remote:        Using nio4r 2.3.1
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.1
remote:        Using arel 9.0.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.3
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.12
remote:        Using msgpack 1.2.6
remote:        Using bundler 2.0.1
remote:        Using byebug 10.0.2
remote:        Using coderay 1.1.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Using thor 0.20.3
remote:        Using ffi 1.10.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Using pg 1.1.4
remote:        Using puma 3.12.0
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Fetching settingslogic 2.0.9
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Using i18n 1.5.3
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.10.1
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
remote:        Using mail 2.7.1
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.3.2
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using uglifier 4.1.20
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
remote:        Using pry 0.12.2
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.2.0
remote:        Using activesupport 5.2.2
remote:        Using loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using pry-byebug 3.6.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Using activemodel 5.2.2
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.8.0
remote:        Using sass 3.7.3
remote:        Using actionview 5.2.2
remote:        Using activejob 5.2.2
remote:        Using activerecord 5.2.2
remote:        Installing settingslogic 2.0.9
remote:        Using actionpack 5.2.2
remote:        Using actioncable 5.2.2
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.2.2
remote:        Using activestorage 5.2.2
remote:        Using railties 5.2.2
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Fetching jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Using rails 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching rails-i18n 5.1.3
remote:        Installing rails-i18n 5.1.3
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Fetching toastr-rails 1.0.3
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Installing toastr-rails 1.0.3
remote:        Bundle complete! 30 Gemfile dependencies, 70 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Removing bundler (2.0.2)
remote:        Bundle completed (4.17s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: uninitialized constant RailsAdmin
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:74:in `block in load_missing_constant'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:74:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:56:in `load_missing_constant'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        
remote:        Caused by:
remote:        NameError: uninitialized constant RailsAdmin
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `block in load_missing_constant'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_c7e64a6acd1b72fa082f3af7a338d12b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to komo-service.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/komo-service.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/komo-service.git'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:1:in "<main>"` suggested that you still have file `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`.

Please double check you have removed it, and add that to your commit before pushing the code.